# Calculate the determinant of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am having some difficulties to calculate a determinant. The matrix is an $n\times n$ one, but I will show the particular case $5\times 5$ in order to simplify the notation.

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & x & x & x\\ 
1 & x & 0 & x & x\\ 
1 & x & x & 0 & x\\ 
1 & x & x & x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

It seems easy but I am missing a step. If for every $i\geq 2$ I add $-x$ times the first row to the $i$th row then I obtain the following matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & -x & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & -x & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & -x & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x
\end{pmatrix}$

and now I can get a recurrence: if $a_n$ is the $n$th determinant, then if I calculate the $n+1$th determinant in terms of the last row, I come up with the formula $a_{n+1}=\left (-1\right )^{n+2}\left (-x\right )^{n-1}-xa_n=-x^{n-1}-xa_n$.

Now, if I consider some small cases I get $a_1=0$, $a_2=-1$, $a_3=2x$, $a_4=-3x^2$, $a_5=4x^3$, $a_6=-5x^4$. It seems to be $a_n=\left (-1\right )^{n+1}\left (n-1\right )x^{n-2}$.

But my problem is that my recursive formula did not help me to prove it by induction. Since I don't think that the conjecture about the general term is wrong, I am for sure commiting a mistake on the recursive formula, but I can't see where exactly. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Suppose the formula holds for the $n \times n$ matrix $A_n$ generalizing the matrix in your second display equation.

Then, we can calculate the determinant of $A_{n + 1}$ by cofactor expansion along the last column. Only the first and the last entries of the last column are zero, and the minor corresponding to the last entry is exact $A_n$, so the cofactor expansion simplifies to
$$\det A_{n + 1} = (-1)^n \det \pmatrix{1 & -x & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & -x \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0} - x \det A_n .$$
Can you compute the determinant in the first term on the r.h.s. and then complete the induction?

Comment: Thank you. I think that your formula is wrong but I came up with the mistake I was commiting by reading your formula. If I calculate the determinant of $A_{n+1}$ the way you suggested, I obtain $\det A_{n + 1} = \left (-1\right )^{n+2} \det \begin{pmatrix}1 & -x & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & -x \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix} -x \det A_n $ (this is where I think you commit a mistake).

Comment: Now if I calculate the determinant of that matrix by cofactor expansion along the last row, then the result is $\left (-1\right )^{n+1}\left (-x\right )^{n-1}=x^{n-1}$, therefore the recursive formula would be $a_{n+1}=\left (-1\right )^{n+2}x^{n-1}-xa_n$, and now I succeeded in proving that $a_n=\left (-1\right )^n\left (n-1\right )x^{n-2}$ by induction.

Comment: Oh, you're right---I've corrected the formula now. Since the matrix is symmetric, by the way, expanding along the last column results in the same expression as expanding along the last row.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: subtract line two from lines 3,4,5 and cevelop by column 1:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & x & x & x\\ 
1 & x & 0 & x & x\\ 
1 & x & x & 0 & x\\ 
1 & x & x & x & 0\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0 & x & x & x\\ 
0 & x &-x & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & x & 0 &-x & 0\\ 
0 & x & 0 & 0 & -x\end{vmatrix}=-\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 x &-x & 0 & 0\\ 
 x & 0 &-x & 0\\ 
 x & 0 & 0 & -x\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{C_1\to C_1+(C_3+C_4)}=$$$${}$$

$$=-\begin{vmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 x &-x & 0 & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 &-x & 0\\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & -x\end{vmatrix}=x\begin{vmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 x &-x & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 &-x 
\end{vmatrix}=-x^2\begin{vmatrix}3&1\\x&\!-x\end{vmatrix}=-x^2(-3x-x)=$$$${}$$

$$=x^3(x+3)$$